# If i rotate in animation, shape breakdown!

Tags: animation

[image]

If i rotate in animation, shape breakdown like above. Why??

Comment: Your weights are wrong. If you don't want anything to bend in your character use the "With Epmty Groups" option when parenting your object to the armature, then assign the vertex groups manually in edit mode.

Comment: You right!  I thought everything red but some parts are little bit red-orange. Thanks!!